# Error 032659 in ArcGIS Pro when using train deep learning tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, deep-learning, error-032659

I'm getting Error 032659 in ArcGIS Pro when using train deep learning tool. I'm getting it from my input data. Below is the error. I've tried saving the file outside of the geodatabase and am still having issues.

[image: Error 032659]

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.

Comment: How is this training data created?